# Triggering a function every time an array value is iterated through

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, timer

I have a timer that cycles through an array of data: It counts down the value of each item in the array then passes to the next item upon completion. I have a function that I would like to trigger when an item's countdown reaches 0 OR when the next item starts being counted.

Context: This is an exercise app and I would like a short whistle sound to be triggered upon an exercise starting, and a slightly longer one to trigger when a break is starting. I know the function triggering the sounds works correctly, but when i try to implement it in the code I have it either triggers every second, or not at all. I am not sure weather this can be solved by placing the exercise inside the existing code or if I should write a function that somehow keeps track of the timer's progress and triggers at the correct time.

JavaScript:

```
var counter = document.getElementById("exerciseCounter");
var current = 0;
var playing = false;
var countdownTimer = null;
var workout = "{
      "title": "Full Body",
      "exercises":
      [
        {
          "name": "Push Ups",
          "duration": 30,
          "break": 10
        },
        {
          "name": "Squats",
          "duration": 30,
          "break": 10
        },
        {
          "name": "Running in Place",
          "duration": 30,
          "break": 10
        }
      ]
    }";

// The function I would like to call every time the timer finishes counting down either a 'duration' value or a "break" value. 
function sounder()
{
  if(label.textContent === "Break")
  {
    soundPlay("sound/long.mp3");
  }
  else
  {
    soundPlay("sound/short.mp3");
  }
}

function soundPlay(src)
{
  var audioElement = document.getElementById("player-src");
  audioElement.src = src;
  var myAudio = document.getElementById("player");
  myAudio.load();
  myAudio.play();
}

// LOOPING TIMER FUNCTION
init();

/**
* Bind loop start to click on button.
*
* @return {void}
*/
function init()
{
  loop();
}

// TIMER FUNCTION
/**
* Timer loop function
*
* @return {void}
*/
function loop()
{
  playing = true;

  // Get current exercise.
  var exercise = workout.exercises[current];

  // If out of the exercises Array's bounds, call 'done'.
  if (!exercise)
  {
    return done();
  }
  // Otherwise run countdown and update UI.
  countdown(exercise.duration, exercise.name, function ()
  {
    countdown(exercise.break, "Break", function ()
    {
      // Next exercise.
      current++;
      // Re-iterate until finished.
      loop();
    });
  });
}

/**
* Exercise session is now over.
*
* @return {void}
*/
function done()
{
  pause();
}

/**
* Recursive timer function.
*
* @param  {Number} seconds
* @param  {String} label
* @param  {Function} callback
* @return {void}
*/
function countdown(seconds, label, callback)
{
  setLabel(label);
  setCounter(seconds);

  // Set timeout to next second.
  countdownTimer = setTimeout(function ()
  {
    // Decrease seconds.
    seconds--;

    // Check whether the countdown is over - execute callback if so.
    if (seconds <= 0)
    {
      return callback();
    }

    // Call itself with a lower number otherwise.
    countdown(seconds, label, callback);
  }, 1000); // (1 sec).
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make use of [`setTimeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) with some minor recursion:

```
var currentExercise = 0;

function doExercise() {
  // The 0th execution will happen before the first exercise starts, so you need to wait for the function to be called again to know it finished
  if (currentExercise !== 0) {
    // Play sounds/do stuff here
    // Remember that you want to be doing things here for `currentExercise - 1`, not `currentExercise`
  }

  // We have done all the exercises
  if (currentExercise >= workout.exercises.length) {
    return;
  }

  var exerciseDurationInMillis = workout.exercises[currentExercise].duration * 1000;

  currentExercise++;

  setTimeout(doExercise, exerciseDurationInMillis);
}

// Start the workout
doExercise(0);
```

The above doesn't include waiting for the breaks, but I think you should be able to figure that out.